# PHP pagination not working properly

Tags: php, pagination

I have written a PHP script to display 5 records per page.

**My Problem :-**
When I type individual page no. in browser it works perfectly fine and display information page by page but it is not showing page numbers at bottom of page.

I have also observed that $sql returns no result, where as the same $sql is working fine when used above in the same script above somewhere.

Thanks for help in advance.

Here is my script for pagination which is not working

```
    <div>
    <?php

    //Now select all from table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE did>0".$search_string.$search_dlocation." order by did desc";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);

    // Count the total records
    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($sql_result);

    //Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

    //Going to first page
    echo "<center><a href='displaydesign.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a> ";

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {

    echo "<a href='displaydesign.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
    };
    // Going to last page
    echo "<a href='displaydesign.php?page=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a></center> ";
    ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Try mysqli_query() instead of mysql_query()

Answer (score 0):

check this line

```
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($sql_result);
```

it should be:

```
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($sql_result);
```

you are using **mysqli** instead of **mysql**.

However try to use mysql**i** as mysql is currently deprecated and removed in PHP7

Comment: I tried making the change as u suggested but its giving following error now.....could not execute SQL querySELECT * FROM designsubmit WHERE did>0 order by did desc

Comment: are you using mysqli or mysql? it seems to me that you are using mysql, if so change `mysqli_num_rows($sql_result)` to `mysql_num_rows($sql_result)`

Comment: @vikramkapoor Great, I edited the my answer so you can accept it as answer.